# Coordinating Layout: Design support library not working

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I was going through some udacity material design classes. I downloaded a project which implements coordinating layout which is working fine I am getting auto complete also for support library, but when I am trying to implement coordinating Layout in my app design support library isn't working as expected neither I am getting auto complete. My code is below

Gradle file(Dependency added)

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    }
```

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="168dp"
            android:background="?colorPrimary">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"  
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">//no auto complete for any app:

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1"
                    app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have also used `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`but auto complete isn't working in my project.

Output that I am getting[image]
There are 3 different views but aren't coordinating with each other.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are expecting

Comment: my app bar isn't collapsing here

Comment: Can everybody stop mixing versions of support libs and act surprised it doesn't work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change your toolbar style to light

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1"
            app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

it will solve your issue